# Django: change the model class returned from a QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building an analytics dashboard, and I'd like to add some dashboard-specific methods to some of the objects I'm querying for. For example, if I've got a `Book` model:

```
class Book(m.Model):
    title = m.CharField()
    author = m.ForeignKey(User)
```

I might want to have a `DashboardBook` class which can summarize the users who viewed the book:

```
class DashboardBook(Book):
    @classmethod
    def query(cls):
        return cls.objects.extra(select={"_raw_recent_views": "SELECT ARRAY(…)"})

    @property
    def recent_views(self):
        return DashboardBookViews(self._raw_recent_views)
```

Is there any way I can sensibly do that?

I've tried this:

```
class DashboardBook(Book):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        abstract = True
        db_table = 'books_book'

    @classmethod
    def query(cls):
        query = cls.objects.all().select_related('user')
        query.model = cls
        return query
```

But some very surprising things happen, like the book's `title` field gets replaced by the user's hashed password.

*Please note*: I am looking *specifically* for how this can be done with a `QuerySet`, because it would be very convenient if I could pass those `QuerySet`s around (just for example, to a `Paginator`). I know there are many ways I could wrap the `QuerySet` (ex, `[DashboardBook(b) for b in Book.objects.all()]`), but that would quickly get hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a Proxy Model : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Also, model specific querying is best implemented using a custom ModelManager than using classmethods.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! (and, yes — the `@classmethod` was just to make the question simple)